# Excel user defined functions processing another workbook

Tags: .net

I am using a function to process values spreaded across workbooks. I understand a subroutine is handy to go with. But Can anybody give a clear cut answer as to whether I can process another workbook using an excel custom function called from current workbook?

Mine brings errors!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an Add-in, and enable it in your Excel environment.

### A. Prepare the Source Workbook.

1. Create your functions in a workbook.
2. Name your workbook and vba project uniquely according to their purpose.
   *The name you give to the file will appear as **the name of the Add-in.***
   *The name you give to the vba project will appear as the global modules in the **Vba code editor**.*
3. Save your work.

### B. Create the Add-in.

1. With your source workbook open, in the normal view (not in the vba editor view), hit Save As.
2. In the Save as type dropdown, select Excel Add-In (*.xlam) or Excel 97-2003 Add-In (*.xla).
   *This will depend on the version of excel where you'll be using the functions.*
   *This will depend on the version of excel where you'll be using the functions.*
3. Locate your new Add-in for future reference. You should find it under the default folder

   ```
    C:\Documents and Settings\padib\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns
   ```

   Otherwise, it's wherever you decided to save it.

### C. Use your new Add-in

1. (2007) Office Button, Excel Options, Add-ins Tab, Manage "Excel Add-ins", Go...
2. (2003) Tools>Add-ins
3. Locate your new Add-in (the name of your source workbook), check it and say OK. If it's not there, browse for the location of the Add-in, OK and OK.

You're done.

### D. Notes

1. You cannot use tab completion for your own functions.
2. For a list of available user defined functions, use the Insert Function dialog box, and find your functions in the User Defined category.

### E. Links

For links, view my blog:

**Technical Me** at 
http://troubleshootingthings.blogspot.com/2010/11/making-user-defined-functions-global-in.html